# python - RGB matrix of an image

Tags: python, image, numpy, python-imaging-library

Taking an image as input, how can I get the rgb matrix corresponding to it? 
I checked out the numpy.asarray function. Does that give me the rgb matrix or some other matrix?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Note that this answer is outdated as of 2018; `scipy` has deprecated `imread`, and you should switch to `imageio.imread`. See [this transition doc](https://imageio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/scipy.html) about differences between the two. The code below should work with no changes if you just import the new library in place of the old, but I haven’t tested it.

---

The simplest answer is to use the NumPy and SciPy wrappers around PIL. There's [a great tutorial](http://scipy-lectures.github.io/advanced/image_processing/), but the basic idea is:

```
from scipy import misc
arr = misc.imread('lena.png') # 640x480x3 array
arr[20, 30] # 3-vector for a pixel
arr[20, 30, 1] # green value for a pixel
```

For a 640x480 RGB image, this will give you a 640x480x3 array of `uint8`.

Or you can just open the file with PIL (or, rather, Pillow; if you're still using PIL, this may not work, or may be very slow) and pass it straight to NumPy:

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
img = Image.open('lena.png')
arr = np.array(img) # 640x480x4 array
arr[20, 30] # 4-vector, just like above
```

This will give you a 640x480x4 array of type `uint8` (the 4th is alpha; PIL always loads PNG files as RGBA, even if they have no transparency; see `img.getbands()` if you're every unsure).

If you don't want to use NumPy at all, PIL's own `PixelArray` type is a more limited array:

```
arr = img.load()
arr[20, 30] # tuple of 4 ints
```

This gives you a 640x480 `PixelAccess` array of RGBA 4-tuples.

Or you can just call `getpixel` on the image:

```
img.getpixel(20, 30) # tuple of 4 ints
```

Comment: An update: `imread` is deprecated in SciPy 1.0.0, and will be removed in 1.2.0. Use `imageio.imread` instead. [source](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.misc.imread.html)

Comment: @HarshitKumar Thanks for the update; I’ll edit it into the answer. Since this is half a decade old, anything else that should be updated?

Answer (score 14):

I have a feeling I'm not doing exactly what you wanted here, so please specify if this is totally off. You could open the image like this and get an array of pixels:

```
import Image
im = Image.open('Lenna.png')
pixels = list(im.getdata())
```

This will get you a flat list of RGB data that looks like

```
[(226, 137, 125), (226, 137, 125), (223, 137, 133), (223, 136, 128), 
 (226, 138, 120), (226, 129, 116), (228, 138, 123), (227, 134, 124), 
 (227, 140, 127), (225, 136, 119), (228, 135, 126), (225, 134, 121),...
```

Now this will be all pixels in a flat array, if you want a two dimensional array then some additional code would be needed for that. Not sure if there is a direct function for it in PIL.

Comment: Yes this is indeed what I want! Just one question, in this list are the pixels in the order of horizontal traversal or vertical traversal of the image? Or is there no order in this data?

Comment: @Ojas: As the docs for [`Image.getdata`](http://pillow.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.getdata) say, "values for line one follow directly after the values of line zero, and so on." However, this is not the best way to do this.

Comment: @Bemmu I'm sorry for replying to your old post. However, I think you might be able to help :) How can I get a numpy array of an RGB image  with `(m, n)` dimensions? For example, two 64X64 pixel RGB images should produce a `(2, 12288)` array. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 6):

I tried `imageio.imread` and it worked great, but a minute later stumbled upon a function in `matplotlib` which worked exactly the same, getting a `numpy` n by m by 3 array:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
image = plt.imread(path)
```

Answer (score 6):

You can do that with `Pillow`, the `getdata` method gives you a flat array of the pixels, you can then build a matrix from that using the `size` of the image.

```py
from PIL import Image

def getPixels(filename):
    img = Image.open(filename, 'r')
    w, h = img.size
    pix = list(img.getdata())
    return [pix[n:n+w] for n in range(0, w*h, w)]
```

Comment: I had to remove the 'r' argument to open to get this to work.

Comment: apparently its the default value for the mode argument anyway, so who knows ^^

Answer (score 1):

Also to add, if you or anyone else is using opencv.

```
 imgc=cv2.imread(file)
```

or to read in as grayscale

```
 imgc=cv2.imread(file,0)
```

If you will be doing some comparison between the images you may want to think about turning the array of pixels into histograms to normalise the data.

```
   hist = np.histogram(img.flatten(),256,[0,256])[0]
```

The above line firstly flattens your img array so you do lose the dimensionality of your image. It then produces bins from 0 to 256 (for the grayscale image) and adds the counts from the img to these bins and returns them as hist which can then be plotted. For example, if the 100 bin has a value of 20 it means that 20 pixels in your image had a value of 100.

Hope this adds another possiblity to think about or to anyone looking to get started in opencv.