# Please tell how to get rgb value of whole image. I have printed rgb value of each pixel

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision

Please tell how to get rgb value of whole image. I have printed rgb value of each pixel

```
import cv2
# LOAD AN IMAGE USING 'IMREAD'
img = cv2.imread("tiger.jpg")
# DISPLAYg
cv2.imshow("Tiger", img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
print(img.shape)
[x,y,z]=img.shape


count=0
for i in range(1,x-1):
    for j in range(1,y-1):
        print(img[i,j]) 
        count=count+1
        print(count)
```

Comment: Explain `"whole image RGB values". Are you trying to calculate the total Amount/Percentage of Red in the Image (RGB) ?

Comment: average? median? minimum? maximum?

Comment: I am trying to take out a single rgb color for an image. In short I have to add rgb value of all pixels in the image, i have to blend all the colors. Please help.

Comment: what you have done is obtainable elegantly [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25102495/10452700) but what you looking for is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11064786/10452700) alternatively you can use [this](https://www.kite.com/python/answers/how-get-the-rgb-values-of-an-image-using-pil-in-python)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you already have pixels. when you read image using

```
img = cv2.imread('tiger.jpg')
```

img contains pixels of your image, you don't need to use loops to get them. you can check it by just printing it like.

```
print(img)

#it gives you something like

[[[182 194 166]
  [182 194 166]
  [182 194 166]
  ...
  [255 176 109]
  [255 176 109]
  [255 176 109]]

 [[182 194 166]
  [182 194 166]
  [182 194 166]
  ...
  [255 176 109]
  [255 176 109]
  [255 176 109]]

 [[182 194 166]
  [182 194 166]
  [182 194 166]
  ...
  [255 176 109]
  [255 176 109]
  [255 176 109]]
  ...
  [132 171 210]
  [135 174 213]
  [137 176 215]]]
```

img is type of numpy array **(numpy.ndarray)** you can check it by this:

```
print(type(img))
```

Comment: For this program:
import cv2

img = cv2.imread("house.jpg")
print(img)
print(type(img))

output is
None
<class 'NoneType'>

Please clearify.

Comment: If you getting "NoneType" it means image is not opened, maybe its not on that place or maybe name or extensions is incorrect.