# How to convert an image into an array of its raw pixel data?

Tags: python, image-processing

I wanted to create a small pixel-by-pixel image manipulation program, so I wanted to ask if there is something (preferably in Python) that can convert a .png image into RGB raw pixel data.

For example, a 3px*3px image like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4dg4d.png) will output:

- [larger image, each square represents one pixel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J3a7R.png)

```
[(255, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0), (255, 0, 0), (0, 255, 0), (0, 255, 0), (0, 255, 0), (0, 0, 255), (255, 255, 255), (0, 0, 255)]
```

The pixel array will be arranged left to right, up to down (regular Western reading style).

**Additional Stuff (If you can do it, it would also be great)**

If the array on top adds additional complications, it would also be ok to print out a list of HSV pixel data instead.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25102495/17201436   ---   is this answer helpful?

Comment: can you give examples for `adds additional complications`  with some number? I don't really get it

Comment: Does this answer your question? [python - RGB matrix of an image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25102461/python-rgb-matrix-of-an-image)

Comment: Any decent image handling library does load images from file to memory in raw RGB format. Read the related documentation about the supported file formats and exact in-memory storage. Select a library that supports RGB to HSV conversion.

Answer (score 0):

Read your image with opencv python.
Few things to notice:

1. PIL a little bit more user friendly, but opencv will serve you really good if you do heavy image processing stuff
2. If you are familar with numpy, I would suggest using opencv because behind the scence, opencv image is actually a numpy array

```
"""
pip install opencv-python
"""
import cv2

im = cv2.imread("test.png")
# Use this to if you read png image
im = cv2.cvtColor(im,cv2.COLOR_BGRA2RGB)
# Use this to if you read jpg image
# im = cv2.cvtColor(im,cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
print(im[0,0])
```

Comment: question is a duplicate, should be flagged as such

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with *Pillow* (PIL) library:

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

path = 'image.png'
image = Image.open(path)
image = np.asarray(image)
```

Notice that returned arrays have a length of 4 because the ".png" format supports an additional Alpha channel (transparency), so it's RGBA.
To get rid of this extra channel, you need to convert an image to RGB format first.

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

path = 'image.png'
image = Image.open(path).convert('RGB')
image = np.asarray(image)
```

Comment: question is a duplicate, should be flagged as such